# Can only boot Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS when holding shift

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a laptop which purely runs Ubuntu (no dual-boot), and whenever I boot my laptop the boot screen goes on without stopping. When I first came across this issue I tried to access GRUB by holding down shift while I booted, however this just caused Ubuntu to boot normally and did not show the GRUB screen at all. I thought this issue could be because GRUB wasn't my default boot manager, however after running `boot-repair`, the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

When you are logged in, open a terminal and type

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then edit these lines to read as such

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
> #GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
> #GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
> #GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Commit these changes, save of with the same name. Then type

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then type

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```